# WebDAV - '/mnt/jfrog/': Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: linux, webdav, fedora-coreos

Installed davfs2 on fedora coreos,
updated secret into /etc/davfs2/secrets file to mount my jfrog artifactory.
Now I created to .mount and .automount file into /etc/systemd/system/ folder and enable both the services.

It it is mounting my drive but the mounted folder in fedora os is not accessible. It is giving an error ***'/mnt/jfrog/': Transfport endpoint is not connected.***

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue reported for davfs2 1.7 on Nov 2022.
https://savannah.nongnu.org/bugs/?63364
I solved this issue :)